# What is the theoretical minimum size of solar cells on wrist watches?

Tags: power-supply, solar-cell

I was wondering what is the theoretical minimum amount of surface area in solar cells one would need to power an analog display wrist watch assuming the following scenario:

The watch's face has a diameter of 42mm.

The expected direct sunlight exposure is 3 hours daily.

The expected indoor light exposure is about 16 hours daily.

We can assume that the watch is an atomic watch, with classic rotating hour, minute, second hands to display the time.

There is a standard 5 year battery found on most wrist-watches.

 **Edit:** As far as power consumption goes, I couldn't find much. I was hoping someone might figure out the power consumption from the above info, but this is the best I could find on a google search:
"A typical watch battery has 30 mAh at 1.55 V, and lasts 5 years.

5 years = 43800 hours.

30 mAh / 43800 hours * 1.55 V = .001 mA V, or 0.000001 watts."

Not being an electrical engineer, I am ignorant of both electronic watch design, and the efficiency and specifics of solar cells. I have tried google, but did not find much on solar watch design.

I would really appreciate the answer in square mm, or better yet a percentage of the size of the face of the watch.

Comment: The solar cell efficiency is irrelevant if you don't specify the watch power consumption.

Comment: Updated question with the info I could find, I hope is adequate info.

Comment: +1 This is a perfectly good design question now that data has been added and fully capable of being answered. Down voters and "vote to close"-ers  need to reverse their actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern Silicon solar cells (PV cells deliver typically 15%+ module efficiency and about 20% is available using the high efficiency (and harder to use) Sunpower cells.

At one sun insolation = 100,000 lux output is

```
  1000 x A x Z Watts
```

A = Area in m^2, Z = efficiency (0 <= Z < 1)

For A in mm^2 above formula gives micro Watts.
**So in full sun at say 15% efficiency you get  150 uW / mm^2 in full sun.**

Bright sky on a sunny day or bright cloud on an overcast day with sun not visible but eye hurting bright is maybe 10% of full sun. Shadow with no direct line to sun is much lower - maybe 0.1% - 1%
Full sun is 100,000 lux so 1% = 1000 lux and 0.1% is 100 lux.

Bright monitor screen backlight full white with cell against surface is about 300 lux = ~~~ 0.3% of full output.
Very bright room - 100 to 1000 lux.
100 lux - view colour pictures with ease (despite what text books say).
20 lux - view colour OK once eyes accustomed. Brighter would be nicer.

Watch covered by shirt sleeve etc ~~= 0lux.
Wear watch at angle to light main source = 10% of available if lucky.

SO a watch in artificial light conditions MAY see 100 - 1000 lux range and less sometimes.

1000 lux = 1% of full sun.
So PV panel gets ~~ 1.5 uW mm^2 at 1000 lux.
Or 0.15 uW/mm^2 at 100 lux.
So your 1 uW watch meeds about 6 mm^2 if illuminated at 100 lux always.
If you can manage 10mm x 10mm = 100 mm^2 then you need about 1/16th of the time at 100 lux or about 1.5 hours per day. A brief burst of full daylight makes a major difference.

E&OE.

ie about 30mm x 30mm or over 1 square inch.

100 lux = 10% of 1000 lux output.